# check CSV file contains no characters but only empty space and tab

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using python v2.7

I have a csv file which could contain only **space** or **tab** without any characters (A-Z and special characters). It looks empty but the size is larger than 0.

How can I check if the csv file contains no characters but only space and tab?

I am using the `csv` module.

```
with open('my.csv', 'r') as my_file:
     # how to check file contains no character though size is larger than 0
```

Comment: csv, that is my typo. corrected now. thanks for notifying me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you plan on doing anything with the CSV file if it's non-empty, the best idea probably is to read it into a list first, so you can still create a `csv.reader` object from it:

```
with open('my.csv', 'r') as my_file:
    lines = my_file.readlines()
if all((line.isspace() for line in lines)): 
    print("Empty file!")
else:
    reader = csv.reader(lines)
    # do stuff
```

Comment: Does it work with tab? I mean does the function `isspace()` return true for tab as well?

Comment: @Leem.fin: Yes, all whitespace characters will be picked up. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isspace

Answer (score 2):

One easy way to do this:

```
with open('my.csv', 'r') as my_file:
     is_blank = len(my_file.read().strip()) == 0
```

(note it will ignore tabs, line jumps and spaces).

Comment: Yes, these kind of things make python great!